# jQuery ajax function returns an error

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

to be honest, I'm a total beginner with jQuery and now I'm stuck. I want to send data from my HTML form to a php, it adds the data to a database and returns some value that I'd like to display on my original HTML. Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://mysite.com/process.php",
  data: { data: mydata },
  cache: false,
  dataType: "text",
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(jqXHR.status);
        alert(jqXHR.statusText);
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    },
  success: function(data){
        getContentBox().innerHTML = data;
}
});
```

It returns a jqXHR object with `status`=0, `statusText`="error" and empty `responseText`. However, my php seems to work, I see my data inserted in my DB. What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
Chrome console says 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mysite.com/data.php. Origin http://www.mysite.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: what headers does your php script send? what output?

Comment: Have you looked at the request/response in Firebug or some other tool?

Comment: PHP just simply prints out the text (print $data;).

Just looked at the request with Chrome: 
Status text: (canceled)
Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Comment: You might try changing the url to [http://www.mysite.com/process.php](http://www.mysite.com/process.php). Cross-Origin can be really picky that: www.domain.com cannot access sample.domain.com.

Comment: Thanks! Not totally this, but changed absolute path to relative (simply process.php) and now it works.

Comment: Hi, you don't need to yell "SOLVED" in titles like as in an old fashioned discussion forum :) Just post an answer (when the time allows it) and mark it accepted. It'll be interpreted as a "solved problem". In the meanwhile you could post a comment on the question indicating that it's already solved and that you'll post the answer later.

Comment: Alright, sorry :).
Solution will come later, as soon as I'm allowed to post it, thanks @ShelbyZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShelbyZ's comment led me to the solution:

The browser refused to execute the request when I tried using an absolute URL, i had to write it as relative.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "process.php",
  data: { data: mydata },
  cache: false,
  dataType: "text",
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(jqXHR.status);
        alert(jqXHR.statusText);
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    },
  success: function(data){
        getContentBox().innerHTML = data;
}
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you forgot to close a bracket) :

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(data){
    getContentBox().innerHTML = data;
  }
});
```

Comment: Ergh, true, in my script it's there, it's just a copy-paste error. Thanks tho.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the built in post function of jquery to simplify this i.e.

```
            $.post('http://mysite.com/process.php', mydata, function(data) {
                if (data.status == 1) {
                    getContentBox().html() = data;
                } else {
                    alert(data.status);
                    alert(data.statusText);
                    alert(data.responseText);
                }
            });
```

im not sure what your status responses are so you may have to edit that but this will work if you put it inside of a `$('form here').submit(function() {POSTCODEHERE});`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Ajax function was bound to the button(type="submit") inside of the `<form>`, so always when I pressed this button my page reloaded and `error` function worked instead of `success`. I really don't know how is this related but when I add `event.preventDefault()` to button's action listener and it's become working fine.