# Jquery AJAX POST call return 200 status OK but error

Tags: javascript, web-services, jquery

Hi I have implemented one Ajax POST request to call web service. It always return 200 OK but execute failed event I have tried lot of things but I am not getting where I am doing mistake. I am adding my code here. [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) shows the response content but Ajax is not executing success event.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: values,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        alert("success:"+result);
    },
    error:function (error) {
        alert("error"+error);
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried dataType:'text'....response from server is in proper JSON format

Request JSON data :

```
{
    "search": {
        "params_attributes": {
            "adults": "1",
            "children": "0",
            "depart_date": "2013-07-10",
            "destination_name": "OMS",
            "direct": "0",
            "infants": "0",
            "origin_name": "KUL",
            "range": "0",
            "trip_class": "0"
        }
    },
    "signature": "XXXXXXXX",
    "marker": "XXX"
}
```

Response JSON data:

```
{
    "search_id":"66",
    "metadata" : {},
    "tickets" : [
        {
            "native_prices":{"7":"5500.0", "6":"5680.0", "3":"5657.0"},
            "order_urls":{"7":"1","6":"557","3":"906"},
            "direct_flights":[
                {
                    "number":"1837",
                    "airline":"FV",
                    "departure":"1294037100",
                    "arrival":"1294041900",
                    "duration":"80",
                    "delay":"0",
                    "origin":"DME",
                    "destination":"LED",
                    "aircraft":"Airbus A319"
                }
            ],
            "return_flights":[
                {
                    "number":"1858",
                    "airline":"FV",
                    "departure":"1295503800",
                    "arrival":"1295508600",
                    "duration":"80",
                    "delay":"0",
                    "origin":"LED",
                    "destination":"DME",
                    "aircraft":"Airbus A320"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
       "airlines": {
          "AB": {
            "alliance_name": null,
            "average_rate": 3.84,
            "deeplink_id": 18,
            "homepage_id": "4ec0ff7b9f1c2760af0049d7",
            "id": 35,
            "name": "airberlin",
            "rates": 377
          },
          "AF": {
            "alliance_name": "SkyTeam",
            "average_rate": 2.89,
            "id": 48,
            "name": "Air France",
            "rates": 292
          }
        },
    "airports":{
          "ALA": {
            "average_rate": 3.66,
            "city": "\u0410\u043b\u043c\u0430\u0442\u044b",
            "country": "\u041a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u0445\u0441\u0442\u0430\u043d",
            "name": "\u0410\u043b\u043c\u0430\u0442\u044b",
            "rates": 60,
            "time_zone": "Asia/Almaty"
          },
          "AMM": {
            "average_rate": 3.42,
            "city": "\u0410\u043c\u043c\u0430\u043d",
            "country": "\u0418\u043e\u0440\u0434\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f",
            "name": "Queen Alia International",
            "rates": 5,
            "time_zone": "Asia/Amman"
          }
    },
    "currency_rates":{"eur":"41.3564", "uah":"3.72911"},
        "gates_info": [
          {
            "average_rate": 4.34,
            "currency_code": "rub",
            "id": 1,
            "is_airline": false,
            "label": "Nabortu",
            "mobile_version": false,
            "payment_methods": [
                "bank",
                "yandex_money",
                "web_money",
                "terminal",
                "card",
                "svyaznoy",
                "euroset"
            ],
            "rates": 336
          },
          {
            "average_rate": 4.34,
            "currency_code": "rub",
            "id": 2,
            "is_airline": false,
            "label": "Davs",
            "mobile_version": false,
            "payment_methods": [
                "cash",
                "bank",
                "yandex_money",
                "web_money",
                "terminal",
                "card",
                "exp",
                "euroset"
            ],
            "rates": 416
          }
        ]
}
```

Ajax error: 
    {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

I am adding screenshots which is taken from firebug please go to tinygrab url to see screenshot:

```
Headers - grab.by/on5Q
Post - grab.by/on5U
Response - grab.by/on5W
Coockies - grab.by/on5Y
```

Comment: Is your webservice on the same domain as this page? If not, you need to use `dataType: 'jsonp'` in order to avoid violating the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Could you Post the JSON Result? Sometimes the Problem lies on the Format na dthe differnt types of quotes.

Comment: No web service is on the other domain. I cannot use 'jsonp' since web service only support POST type request.

Comment: Some more Context would be needed or the answers will only be guess work? Interessing Information (for me): Json result, Error Object / Message, Result when you set the `dataType`to `text` this things could help.

Comment: I checked the data, buit i just can deduce, that this problem might have to due with the crossdomain policy of the service. That is the only sence i can make out of this data. have you tried downloading the clientaccesspolicy.xml to see what it states? It's a long shot since you said you see the result in fiddler, but you never know. I hope this pointer might help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery ajax function returns an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482530/jquery-ajax-function-returns-an-error)

Comment: Have you found already an solution? If so please share. THX :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without seeing the JSON Response i would have to guess, that the Problem is, that you are using the Wrong(or no) Quotes for the JSON. You must use **double** Quotes(for property names and string values), or at least when i had that problem, the double quotes solved it.

Example:

```
{"id":1,"name":"TOM"}
```

i hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but I have used double quotes for the JSON.

Comment: Could you post the JSON result in your Question? Since it seems to work when you use dataType:text and it doesnt when you use dataType:json, so it has to do with the response.

Comment: Looks like OP's response is a valid json, my case is due to error json format, http://jsonlint.com helped my catch the problem.

Comment: and in my case I haven't been returning anything at all.. (only status 200) wich is still an invalid json

Answer (score 2):

For other friends that have such an error, try to return a JSON value to the page that you send your values from.

In my case, I'm on `localhost:8080/sender` page that sends JSON data to `localhost:8110/receiver` page. After receiver page gets the data, return something like `{}` back to the sender page. Otherwise, the error callback is called even if the server returns a 200 HTTP code.